# Genius: The Transgression house rules

Tags: house-rules, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, genius-the-transgression

I gather that work on the **Genius: The Transgression** fansplat has ceased, since there haven't been updates in 2 years on the official site. However, I'm having trouble with some of the gameplay and would like to see alternate ways of doing things. Is there any official (or at least sizeable) community discussing houserules I can join? Any published variant rules I can examine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Genius: The Transgression** was developed on RPG.NET; as a result, you'll find the mass of its fan base and development community there. [Here's a link](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?566161-Genius-the-Transgression-PhD/page84) to the most current thread on the game; its origins can be found at [this link](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?392121-Genius-The-Transgression).